# Can someone point me the best way to integrate/connect sharepoint to TYPO3?

Tags: sharepoint, integration, typo3

I'm currently working on a project requesting to integrate or connect Sharepoint to TYPO3.

Share point will somehow replace the fileadmin of TYPO3.
So what I mean by "integrate" or "connect" is the following points:

- To display lists of documents from sharepoint on TYPO3 pages through the TYPO3 BE by using some tag or category. In short accessing sharepoints document in the TYPO3 BE.
- To be able through TYPO3 to search documents from Sharepoint. And to filter them by type or category. And of course to display the results.

---

I found some references on the web.

- The obvious one was the [sharepoint connector SPTools of TYPOTYCOON](http://www.typotycoon.com/products/sharepoint-connector/) but it seems dead as there are no fresh news on the website and no activity on the twitter account.
- I found also two extensions on the TER (WSS/MOSS Reader and WSS/MOSS Writer) last uploaded December 2010. Surely outdated - Did anyone ever used them? have some feedback?
- I found also some references about [CMIS and the TYMIS extension](http://typo3-fr.org/choisir-typo3/actu-francophone/actualite-10.html?tx_ttnews%5btt_news%5d=79&cHash=017e17350ee2714136ba820ee2600b14) but couldn't find it on the TER.

---

That's why I come to you, hoping you have some solution, useful feedback or lead at least...

Answer (score 1):

Starting in TYPO3 6.0 the new *File abstraction Layer (FAL)* [1.] was introduced. This gives you the possibility to split the file storage from the files used in TYPO3. As the result fileadmin might contain any number of virtual mount points of any supported storage. Multiple (local, WebDAV) FAL drivers come preinstalled and there is an Amazon S3 driver at [2.]. I am not aware of any FAL driver development for Sharepoint. So this might be up to you to resolve, but these hints should get you started.

Links:

1. http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/FileAbstractionLayerReference/
2. http://git.typo3.org/TYPO3v4/Extensions/fal_amazons3.git

Comment: You should write a FAL driver or hire someone to do so. It would be nice if you would share the code with the community later on :)